# New MS Entra MFA users with AD FS not correctly bypassing MFA requirement to allow initial ProofUp

Tags: entra-id, adfs, azure-mfa, multi-factor-authentication

I'm preparing to onboard a new set of users for MFA authentication with Entra/AD FS, and running into some trouble (thankfully still during the testing phase!)

The environment is an on-premise AD/AD FS server (2019), synching to Entra with P1 to support MFA. This is working for most users. When users activate a new account they are redirected to the MS "ProofUp" process at mysignins.micrsoft.com/security-info per the documentation, and can finish the registration/authentication. It allows them to initially bypass the MFA requirement to reach the "mysignins.micrsoft.com/security-info" page until additional factors are provided, as it should.

However, we have a class of users now who come to us where they already have the Microsoft Authenticator app, and have already signed into the app with our "Work or School account", but have not yet actually finished registering the app for MFA with our Azure/Entra tenant. Notably, the app does NOT appear at all in the Authentication Methods section for the user in the Entra admin console. These are students (we are a university) who used the app to do MFA with an outside service from back before we required student MFA, and we now no longer use that service.

These users are NOT able to load the mysignins.micrsoft.com/security-inf ProofUp page, and instead enter a redirect loop where they continually end up back at our AD FS site saying they need to complete MFA registration.

[image: AD FS MFA required screen shot]

One key is **at no point does the user ever see an actual error message.** They just can't move past the AD FS page asking them to register MFA tokens. Anything they do to move forward will redirect them back to this point. Additionally, sign-in logs for these users in Entra will only show "Success" results unless they actual do enter a bad password, and even these are from before we turn on the MFA requirement for the user (or after we release them due to failure).

---

**UPDATE**:

I am now able to recreate this for a *new* test user on demand with these steps:

1. Create a user in the local Active Directory
2. Make sure the user is NOT yet required for MFA and let it sync to Azure AD/Entra
3. Take a test mobile device that is NOT already registered with Entra
4. Install the MS Authenticator app fresh on the device (completely remove it first and then re-install if it's already there so any local data for prior tests is cleared)
5. Login to the Authenticator app as a work/school account with the user credentials created in step 1
6. Close and quit the app.
7. Set the user to require MFA for one of our AD FS Relying Parties (we do that here by adding a group membership in AD)
8. Have the user try to access a protected app

The important thing was steps 5 and 6 happened before step 7.

AD FS will now correctly determine the user needs to complete MFA; it will show them a message [per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-and-azure-mfa#customize-the-ad-fs-web-page-to-guide-users-to-register-mfa-verification-methods) and then attempt to redirect them to the Entra ProofUp page after 5 seconds. But the proof-up page will not allow access and immediately redirect them back to AD FS to repeat the cycle. The user is prevented from completing the ProofUp process.

---

Using the "Require Re-register multifactor authentication" button shown below for the user in the admin console does *not* work to resolve this.

[image: Entra partial screenshot showing button]

So far, I have two ways I can move these users forward:

1. Manually enter an additional factor for them (such as a cell phone). We'll soon be brining several hundred additional users onboard this way, where I don't necessarily have those cell phone numbers. I need something better.
2. Change the access control policy for the Office 365 app specifically to not require MFA. This isn't as bad as it seems at first, because we use Google Workspace for email and most document services, but it's also obviously not good and not something I want to live with long term.

How can I clear the half-finished Authenticator app registration for these users, or otherwise allow them to move forward with MFA registration?

I *can't* be the first person to run into this, because it could happe to anyone who skips a step in the normal process and tries to add the Authenticator App too soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we're going to work around this issue:

I added an additional group to AD for managing MFA called `MFA_ProofUpBypass`.
Then I created a new Access Control Policy in AD FS with three criteria:

1. Permit everyone except from the MFA_Required group
2. Permit users from the MFA_Required group and require multi-factor authentication except from the MFA_ProofUpBypass group
3. Permit users from the MFA_ProofUpByPass group

[image: Access Control Policy image]

After successfully testing the policy, I applied it to our Micrsoft 365 relying party (and **only** this relying party) in AD FS.

Now, as we add new users from this population (in batches of about 30/week, because we only have a two-person support team who also still need to handle regular requests, too), we will initially add users to *both* the `MFA_Required` and `MFA_ProofUpBypass` group at the same time.

In this way, these users will be able to complete their MFA registration process, and existing MFA users won't lose account protection for the Microsoft 365 service.

Then, as we know each batch has successfully completed registration we can remove them from the `MFA_ProofUpBypass` group, so they will also have MFA protection for the Microsoft 365 service.

Going forward, as we have normal user churn and issues we can continue to use the `MFA_ProofUpByass` group to help support users for this kind of issue as well things like transferring to a new phone.

---

I'd still like to fully solve this, but I'm out of time (sort of - we don't start till next term, but I need senior leadership to approve the migration plan this week before the holidays).

Comment: Considering moving this app (and only this app for now) to an Entra "Enterprise App", so the sign-in doesn't go through AD FS in the first place. Eventually this is what we want for all of our apps (one less server on campus, allows online students to login if campus internet is down, better security controls, etc), but getting there won't be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Azure Active Directory > Users > All users > Choose the user you wish to perform an action on > select Authentication methods > Require Re-register MFA
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/howto-mfa-userdevicesettings#next-steps

**Update:
Here is a script also used by Microsoft support to analyze the adfs logs. Might be helpful**
[https://github.com/CSS-Identity/ADFS-Diag/](https://github.com/CSS-Identity/ADFS-Diag)

Comment: I will try this, but I was thinking it hadn't worked.

Comment: Confirmed this does **NOT** fix this issue for those users.

Comment: Any errors in the logs when doing that with a user? Sign-in logs or audit logs?

Comment: Again please Enable detailed logging for AD FS and entra id authentication to capture any specific errors or events during the MFA registration attempts

Comment: There are lots of sign in logs, but **all** them for my test user show "success". There are only three audit logs, but they all correlate to actions I took as an admin.

Comment: Still going through AD FS logs, but it's a slow process (we have a lot of traffic on the server, and it's compounded because there are 5 York Universities in the world, and one of the others has students consistently pick our institution when signing in to a service we both use, putting LOTS of junk into our logs.) Which is to say, it's past 5 here on a Friday so I'm going home and will pick up again later.

Comment: Sounds time to engage Microsoft support